# Add an increasing number to the end of text from .Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have text in a .Value that I want to add a increasing number to for each row. The text is "J1.", and I want to add 1 to the end of it. The final output should be J1.1, J1.2, J1.3 etc for each row that is returned.

```
For CurCol = 2 To LastCol
If .Cells(22, CurCol).Value = "" Then
    ' Do Nothing
Else
    DestRow = Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'Quantity
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = "1"
    'Bar Size
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = .Range("B16")
    'Bar Mark
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("D" & DestRow).Value = "J1"
    'Shape
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("E" & DestRow).Value = "17"
    'B Dimension
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("G" & DestRow).Value = .Range("C20")
    'C Dimension
    Sheets("Barlist").Range("H" & DestRow).Value = .Cells(22, CurCol).Value
End If
Next CurCol
```

Comment: are you speaking only of column D?

Answer (score 0):

Using what you've got here as a start.
**Add a counter and increment it as you go,** concatenating the string "J1." & count.

```
Dim lCount As Long
lCount = 1

For CurCol = 2 To LastCol
    If .Cells(22, CurCol).Value = "" Then
        ' Do Nothing
    Else
        DestRow = Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'Quantity
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = "1"
        'Bar Size
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = .Range("B16")
        'Bar Mark
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("D" & DestRow).Value = "J1." & lCount 'THIS LINE
        'Shape
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("E" & DestRow).Value = "17"
        'B Dimension
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("G" & DestRow).Value = .Range("C20")
        'C Dimension
        Sheets("Barlist").Range("H" & DestRow).Value = .Cells(22, CurCol).Value
        lCount = lCount + 1
    End If

Next CurCol
```

Comment: Looks to be on the right path but it only returned "J1.1" for every row.